# Why the size of class showing 12 and 16 byte?

Tags: c++, class, virtual-functions

I have five classes here, class A B C I can explain the size of them.

class D I expect the result is **12 bytes**, but the output is **16 bytes**, I found the reason is that after adding the virtual function, the alignment will become **8 bytes**,

So I created the Test class again, according to the above reasoning, my expected result is **16 bytes**, but after running, the result is **12 bytes**,

Should not the Test class is also **8 bytes** alignment, and the result should be **16 bytes**?
Or what causes the class to perform **8 bytes** alignment?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    //empty
};

class B
{
    int a = 123;
};

class C
{
    public:
        void print(){
            cout << "C" << endl;
        }
    private:
        int i = 123;
};

class D
{
    public:
        virtual void print(){
            std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
        }
        virtual int d(){
            return 0;
        }
        void add(){
            std::cout << "D add" << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        int i;
};

class Test
{
    private:
        int i;
        int j;
        int l;
};
int main(){
    cout << sizeof(A) << endl;//1 byte:avoid null pointer
    
    cout << sizeof(B) << endl;//4 bytes:one int
    
    cout << sizeof(C) << endl;//4 bytes:one int

    cout << sizeof(D) << endl;//16 bytes(using 12byte):one int + one pointer and 8 alignment
    
    cout << sizeof(Test) << endl;//12 bytes:Why not 16 bytes?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Test` has 3 members of the same alignment which on your platform seems to be 4 bytes. Why do you think it should be 8?

Comment: and for D it's one int + an 8-byte pointer + 4 bytes of padding (not 8)

Comment: @ixSci I think OP consider `D` has padding, so `Test` should have padding as well.

Comment: Alignment of every `int` (assuming a 32-bit `int`, which is what your compiler provides) is a four byte boundary, so the only requirement for alignment of a `Test` is that every `int` is on a four-byte boundary.   There is no requirement for 16 bit alignment of the `Test` as a whole.       Unlike `D`, a `Test` does not have virtual functions so (for compilers that include a pointer to a vtable in each instance of a class with virtual functions - which apparently your compiler does) `D` will have a vtable but a `Test` will not.

Comment: I thought the largest alignment should be used in any case, but in fact it should be the same as the largest data type, is that right?

Comment: The compiler has to choose an alignment so that, if you create an array of structs, all members of all elements will be properly aligned. It has little to do with the size of the members, more with their required alignment.

Comment: For example, adding a virtual function adds a pointer to the struct (usually at the start, to be easy to find). This makes the whole struct aligned as the alignment of this pointer.

Comment: The size of an empty class is not 1 in order to "avoid null pointer", it is 1 in order to give every object its own unique location. (If you have an array `A as[3]`, you can't have `&as[0] + 1 == &as[0] + 2`.)

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> class D I expect the result is 12 bytes, but the output is 16 bytes

Your expectation is misguided.

> I found the reason is that after adding the virtual function, the alignment will become 8 bytes,

That's the reason. 12 is not aligned to 8 bytes. 16 is.

> So I created the Test class again, according to the above reasoning, my expected result is 16 bytes, but after running, the result is 12 bytes,

You didn't add virtual functions to `Test`, so your expectation is wrong.

> Should not the Test class is also 8 bytes alignment,

There's no reason to expect that.

> Or what causes the class to perform 8 bytes alignment?

In this case, it was caused by having a virtual member function. In other cases it can also be caused by having a sub object with alignment of 8.